# problems installing esptool with pip to native environment

Tags: python-3.x, linux, esp32, vscodium

I am trying to install something for a project I'm working on and I get this error. I have gotten this error when trying to install "esptool" and searched for a couple hours to solve the issue. It worked in a "virtual environment" but would not work in `VSCodium`. I am working in Linux parrot 6.1.0-1parrot1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Parrot 6.1.15-1parrot1 (2023-04-25) x86_64 GNU/Linux. And I am using Python 3.9.2.

I'm not the most fluent in Linux but I'm trying to learn as I go. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first question on stackoverflow so if my formatting is wrong I apologize. I'm sure I'm forgetting details so please ask for more info and I will try to provide it.

```
pip3 install esptool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pip==20.3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')())
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.packaging.utils import canonicalize_name
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
    vendored("requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1556, in <module>
    class X509StoreFlags(object):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1577, in X509StoreFlags
    CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
```

I am reading directions from an online tutorial and following them line by line so when I get to an issue like this I generally look the issue up and try to figure out what to do. This issue seems pretty complex and has me stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit the crypto.py file (it will be present at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py) and comment out the line causing the issue (line no 1577) by adding a # at the start of the line

Then upgrade to the latest version of PyOpenSSL.

```
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
```

Next remove the # and try to install esptool again and it should be working